# Como ordenar uma busca no MySQL com data no formato date para pegar só o mês

Tags: mysql

Tenho um campo `date`, gostaria de fazer uma `query` para pegar somente o mês desse campo.
Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta utilizar a função `MONTH` do `MySQL`.

```
SELECT MONTH(seu_campo);
```

Comment: Bem isso... Mas meu problema não é esse, eu quero fazer um variável em php que receba esse valor e ordene por essa variável... entende?

Comment: Faça sua `query` e no final coloque o seguinte `ODER BY MONTH(seu_campo)`.

Comment: Não resolve... queria algo mas ou menos assim $query = "SELECT * FROM tabela ORDER BY MONTH(campo, $variavel)". Entende?

Comment: Então o que você quer é listar somente as linhas em que o campo `date` for correspondente ao mês da sua variável no `PHP`?

Comment: Isso amigão... Tem como fazer isso?

Comment: Você pode simplificar a operação fazendo o tratamento no select e usando uma variável interna da consulta para as cláusulas WHERE e ORDER: 

SELECT MONTH(data) AS mes FROM tabela WHERE mes = '$variavel' ORDER BY mes

Comment: Então sua `query` ficaria assim `SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE MONTH(seu_campo) = $variavel`.